# Data analysis software

Tags: software

Several years ago(it may have been over 10 years) I used some software for a little bit that was really cool for exploring large data sets. Unfortunately I don't remember anything about it(I didn't use it that much at the time).

What I remember is that it had a nice visualization window that let you view the data. IIRC it let you view binary files or anything you wanted and it would display it in a large cube(it had more than one way to visualize it) and you see hidden patterns inside the cube of data due to the way it plotted the data. It could handle gigs worth of data.

I just remember being really impressed with it at the time. It had a sleek interface for the time and the way it looked was nice.

I've tried to find it online by looking at data analysis programs but can't seem to seem to find anything like it. IIRC it was more for analyzing things related to computer data rather than arbitrary data but I could be wrong. The color scheme of the data was like flame yellow or something(I'm sure it could be changed)

Any ideas what the software might be? I'll know it if I see it.

---

Ok, using google I was able to find this: https://github.com/codilime/veles

The visualization looks just like this more or less. I do not remember this being the software though but it is very close so it might have been.

Is there anything comparable to this out there that has a more professional interface with more data analysis tools?

Comment: Hi! You should try asking your question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ , you'll be more likely to get answers.